# Filter a query set in Django based on aggregate of one of its fields for a foreign key?

Tags: python, django, subquery, django-orm

Consider the following two models, `Worker` and `Invoice`:

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Invoice(models.Model):
    worker = models.ForeignKey(
        'Worker', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

I would like to perform a query for only those `Invoice`s for which the total (the sum of `amount`s) is greater than zero for a given `Worker`.

Basically, I would like to define a `get_payable_invoices()` function which returns a `Queryset` such that the test passes:

```
from decimal import Decimal

from django.test import TestCase
from django.db.models import Sum

from myapp.models import Worker, Invoice


def get_payable_invoices():
    return Invoice.objects.filter(
        worker__in=Worker.objects.annotate(Sum('invoice__amount')))\
        .filter(invoice__amount__sum__gt=0)


class PayableInvoicesTests(TestCase):
    def test_get_payable_invoices(self):
        worker1 = Worker.objects.create(name="John Doe")

        invoice1 = Invoice.objects.create(
            worker=worker1, amount=Decimal('100.00'))
        invoice2 = Invoice.objects.create(
            worker=worker1, amount=Decimal('-150.00'))

        worker2 = Worker.objects.create(name="Mary Contrary")
        invoice3 = Invoice.objects.create(
            worker=worker2, amount=Decimal('200.00'))

        self.assertEqual(get_payable_invoices().count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(get_payable_invoices().first(), invoice3)
```

The current implementation doesn't work, though, and returns a

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'invoice' into field. Choices are: amount, id, worker, worker_id
```

It seems that although the objects returned when iterating over the query set do have the `invoice__amount__sum` attribute, it cannot be used in `filter()` in this way.

It seems to me that I should formulate the query along the lines of the one in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#using-aggregates-within-a-subquery-expression, but I'm struggling to adapt that example to mine because `total_comments` returns a single number, whereas I want a list of `Worker`s. I'm also not entirely sure whether subqueries is the right way to go, or whether this could be done in a simpler way without them. Any ideas on how to achieve such a query in Django?

Comment: Are you sure the queryset do have `invoice__amount__sum`? I think it should be `Sum(invoice_set__amount)` in the aggregate function since you didn't explicitly specify the `related_name` for `Invorce.worker`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations, that when filtering on annotations, you need to use a different name than the default name to 'disambiguate'. The following function makes the test pass:

```
def get_payable_invoices():
    return Invoice.objects.filter(
        worker__in=Worker.objects
        .annotate(invoice_total=Sum('invoice__amount'))
        .filter(invoice_total__gt=0))
```

I've also verified that one query is executed. For example, I can add the following to the bottom of the unit test:

```
    with self.assertNumQueries(1):
        for invoice in get_payable_invoices():
            pass
```